# Making a pdo wrapper

Tags: php, pdo

With PDO you can connect to different drivers, MySQL, SQLITE and so on. I am wondering what a nice way is to implement this on my wrapper.

My first idea was to have a Factory pattern which creates the PDO object (depending on driver specificed) and then simply inject the PDO object to the wrapper.

Something like this:

```
<?php

class db
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(PDO $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
        ...
    }
}


class factory {
    public function create($driver = 'mysql')
    {
        switch ($driver) {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Any better suggestions on making the wrapper as flexible and reusable as possible?  Or is my proposed solution a good one?

Comment: Why do you think you need a wrapper anyway?

Comment: What about just subclassing `PDO` and doing some additional work in the constructor? There's no clear answer for this since there's no clear goal here.

Comment: You may want to use Doctrine to wrap pdo.  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html. It's very easy to load Doctrine into your code base using composer http://getcomposer.org/.

Answer (score 1):

Your CRUD commands would need to be different depending on your database, MySQL and SQLITE have MINOR differences in the way they do table creations/alters, row replaces, and row updates.  If you include them in the same file, be careful you aren't sending the same commands to both MySQL and SQLITE.

Comment: Why do you need two factories? There is not (at least I hope not) going to be any sql in the factories. The factories should simply build instances.

Comment: I don't know, stop yelling at me. :(  All I was suggesting is that he separate his MySQL and SQLite statements.

Comment: I'm very sorry if in some way you thought I was yelling at you or you are in some way offended by my constructive question.

Comment: Haha, no it's ok. I did not mean to insinuate that you were rude.  It was tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: Damn this internet thing is hard :P